# Assigning a value to multiple keys in object literal

Tags: javascript

Like how you can have:

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = obj.b = 5;
obj.a === obj.b === 5; //just imagine that it won't evaluate to true === 5
```

Is there the same thing for object literals? Something along the line of:

```
var obj = {
    a : b : 5
};
obj.a === obj.b === 5; //just imagine that it won't evaluate to true === 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there the same thing for object literals?

No, there isn't. Although you can use any other expression on the right-hand side of the `:`, including an assignment expression, you can't use another property initialization expression. And you can't use an assignment expression instead (assigning to one of that object's properties) because the object hasn't been assigned to the target variable yet, so you have no way of referencing it.